# Are the sliders in Adobe Camera Raw input color space independent?

Tags: photo-editing, digital, color-spaces, adobe-camera-raw

Are the sliders (shadows/highlights) in Adobe Camera Raw affecting the device-dependent data before transformation to device-independent color space, or does this transformation happen after the input data was already converted to a device-independent working space?

If the latter, does the TRC of the input->independent conversion matter for the correct functionality of the sliders? In other words, do they expect a delinearized camera input profile?

I would be interested in creating a flat input profile for my camera, for example [using DCamProf](https://www.ludd.ltu.se/~torger/photography/camera-profiling.html), but before going through all that effort I'd like to know if Adobe Camera Raw would be confused by a flat TRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, no, you can't work in ACR/Lightroom with a linear input profile.

From the developer of [DCamProf](https://www.ludd.ltu.se/~torger/dcamprof.html) on a [Luminous Landscape thread](http://forum.luminous-landscape.com/index.php?topic=103292.msg848077#msg848077).

> All Adobe's profiles apply a curve, and afaik all have subjective tunings too to provide a pleasing color appearance with that curve applied. You can't really work in Lightroom with a linear colorimetric profile and get good color appearance for general purpose photography, as all the tools to apply contrast will distort color in one way or another.